# grep string after first occurrence of numbers

Tags: linux, string, unix, grep

How do I get a string after the first occurrence of a number?

For example, I have a file with multiple lines:

```
  34 abcdefg
10 abcd 123
    999 abc defg
```

I want to get the following output:

```
abcdefg
abcd 123
abc defg
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the following two input files :

```
  001 ham
03spam
  3 spam with 5 eggs
```

A quick solution with awk would be :

```
awk '{sub(/[^0-9]*[0-9]+/,"",$0); print $1}' <file>
```

This line substitutes the first string of anything that does not contain a number followed by a number by an empty set (`""`).  This way `$0` is redefined and you can reprint the first field or the remainder of the field. This line gives exactly the following output.

```
ham
spam
spam
```

If you are interested in the remainder of the line

```
awk '{sub(/[^0-9]*[0-9]+ */,"",$0); print $0}' <file>
```

This will have as an output :

```
ham
spam
spam with 5 eggs
```

Be aware that an extra `" *"` is needed in the regular expression to remove all trailing spaces after the number. Without it you would get

```
awk '{sub(/[^0-9]*[0-9]+/,"",$0); print $0}' <file>

 ham
spam
 spam with 5 eggs
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! however,

awk '{sub(/[^0-9]*[0-9]+/,"",$0); print $1}'

only prints until the next space symbol. Is there a way to print rest of the string?

Comment: @Jeugasce, replace `print $1` with `print $0`, note that it is possible to have remaining spaces before the string this way. The second awk line will remove the spaces and print the full line.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Awk for this, loop through all the columns in each line upto `NF` (last column in each line) and once matching the first word, print the column next to it. The `break` statement would exit the for loop after the first iteration.

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /[[:digit:]]+/) { print $(i+1); break } }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you exactly want, but you can try to express it in `sed`.
Remove everything until the first digit, the next digits and any spaces.

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*[0-9]\+ *//'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove digits and whitespaces using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9 ]+//' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, I need to remove the first occurrence of digits only as the string I need might have digits.

Comment: @Jeugasce Maybe (no, definitely) you should add that requirement to your original question along with some sample lines to test against.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` can do the job:

```
$ grep -o -P '(?<=[0-9] ).*' inputFIle
abcdefg
abcd 123
abc defg
```

For completeness, here is a solution with `perl`:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /[0-9]+\s*(.*)/' inputFIle
abcdefg
abcd 123
abc defg
```